# unable to change text attr("y") in d3.js using function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a simple demo in d3.js - mouseover should increase the size of the circle and display text "Hello", mouseout does the opposite.

Here's the codepen link - http://cdpn.io/LzIjt

When I try to link the "y" value of the text to the "cy" value of the circle, the text doesn't display. However, it works fine for "x"

Success - text displays -

```
vis.append("svg:text")
  .attr("x",function()
        {
          return (d3.select("circle").attr("cx") - 17);
        })
  .attr("y",103)
  .text("Hello")
  .attr("visibility","hidden");
```

Fails - text doesn't display -

```
 vis.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x",function()
            {
              return (d3.select("circle").attr("cx") - 17);
            })
      .attr("y",function()
            {
              return (d3.select("circle").attr("cy") + 3);
            })
      .text("Hello")
      .attr("visibility","hidden");
```

Am i missing something with the way the attributes work?

Thanks!

~Madhu

Answer (score 2):

One of the great things about D3 is you can use the console and inspect elements in a browser like Chrome. Viewing your "doesn't work" sample, it appears your "cy" value was showing as 1003.

So your select here
`return (d3.select("circle").attr("cy") + 3);`
returns the value of `1003`.

But if you make sure your selection is treated as an integer, then the 
function
`return ( parseInt(d3.select("circle").attr("cy"), 10) + 3);`
returns the value of `103`.

See the code in action here, 
and be sure to check out the console.

http://jsfiddle.net/2qQdx/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the +.
With x subtraction works:

```
return (d3.select("circle").attr("cx") - 17);
```

addition doesn't:

```
return (d3.select("circle").attr("cx") + 17);
```

Unless you force it to do math not concatenate by adding * 1 before the 17:

```
return (d3.select("circle").attr("cx") * 1 + 17);
```

Same with y:

Works with subtraction:

```
return (d3.select("circle").attr("cy") - 3);
```

Doesn't work with addition:

```
return (d3.select("circle").attr("cy") + 3);
```

Unless you force it to use the cy attr as a number by adding * 1:

```
return (d3.select("circle").attr("cy") * 1 + 3);
```

Someone else may have a cleaner solution, but it is an issue with concatenation vs addition.